# Liferay lfr_session_state cookie

Tags: liferay-6

I am new to Liferay. Our recent penetration tests on our application reported a session fixation vulnerability with lfr_session_state cookie. Have not found online resources on what the purpose of this cookie is. Could anyone throw some light on what this cookie is and the purpose of it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

LFR_SESSION_STATE_* cookies are created and managed from client-side javascript ([session.js code](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/master/modules/apps/frontend-js/frontend-js-aui-web/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/liferay/session.js)) and they are used only for controlling timestamp of user session expiration: a javascript warning is displayed to user when its session is about to expire or expired, without doing any request to Liferay server.

As they are not sent to server and they only control session timeout warning, they are not problematic.

They are not configured with the "httpOnly" or "secure" flags as they are a client-only cookie.